# Are there any SEO benefits to gzipping sitemap.xml?

Tags: seo, sitemap, xml-sitemap, gzip

Are there any SEO benefits to serving up a compressed sitemap instead of just plain XML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no SEO benefits to serving a compressed XML sitemap over serving one that is not compressed.

The advantage of compression is simply to save bandwidth and the time it takes to download. (If your sitemap is huge.)

Note that the limits for the size of the sitemap are the *uncompressed* size (ie. 50MB uncompressed for Google).

Comment: And 50,000 entries per file. If you need more than 50,000, then an index sitemap is required. Just in case the OP needed to know...